# asp.net high number of Request Queued and Context switching

Tags: asp.net, performance

We have a fairly popular site that has around 4 mil users a month. It is hosted on a Dedicated Box with 16 gb of Ram, 2 procc with 24 cores.

At any given time the CPU is always under 40% and the memory is under 12 GB but at the highest traffic we see a very poor performance. The site is very very slow.  We have 2 app pools one for our main site and one for our forum. Only the site is being slow. We don't have any restrictions on cpu or memory per app pool.

I have looked at he Performance counters and I saw something very interesting. At our peek time for some reason Request are being queued. Overall context switching numbers are very high around 30 - 110 000 k.

As i understand high context switching is caused by locks. Can anyone give me an example code that would cause a high number of context switches.

Comment: Anyone any suggestions or any code samples that would lead to high context switches. Since we have a lot of small files taht we are serving trough http handler is it possbile that this is causing the problem. All files are stored in one folder and there is approx 200 000 files in that folder

Comment: As suggested by many articles I whas also monitoring perf counter .NET CLR LocksAndThreads(w3wp)\Contention Rate / sec and this one .NET CLR LocksAndThreads(w3wp)\Current Queue Length to verify that I have a locking issue that is causing high number of context switchs. But all the time both perf counters have value of 0. Please any suggestions or help

Comment: Synchronous IO is blocking, meaning it will jam up a worker process and cause requests to be queued while the worker finishes. I suspect the handlers are reading these small files synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too concerned with the context switching, and i don't think the numbers are huge. You have a lot of threads running in IIS (since its a 24 core machine), and higher context switching numbers re expected. However, I am definitely concerned with the request queuing.

I would do several things and see how it affects your performance counters:

1. Your server CPU is evidently under-utilized, since you run below 40% all the time. You can try to set a higher value of "Threads per processor limit" in IIS until you get to a 50-60% utilization. An optimal value of threads per core by the books is 20, but it depends on the scenario, and you can experiment with higher or lower values. I would  recommend trying setting a value >=30. Low CPU utilization can also be a sign of blocking IO operations.
2. Adjust the "Queue Length" settings in IIS properties. If you have configured the "Threads per processor limit" to be 20, then you should configure the Queue Length to be 20 x 24 cores = 480. Again, if the requests are getting Queued, that can be a sign that all your threads are blocked serving other requests or blocked waiting for an IO response.
3. Don't serve your static files from IIS. Move them to a CDN, amazon S3 or whatever else. This will significantly improve your server performance, because 1,000s of Server requests will go somewhere else! If you MUST serve the files from IIS, than configure IIS file compression. In addition use expire headers for your static content, so they get cached on the client, which will save a lot of bandwidth.
4. Use Async IO wherever possible (reading/writing from disk, db, network etc.) in your ASP.NET controllers, handlers etc. to make sure you are using your threads optimally. Blocking the available threads using blocking IO (which is done in 95% of the ASP.NET apps i have seen in my life) could easily cause the thread pool to be fully utilized under heavy load, and Queuing would occur.
5. Do a general optimization to prevent the number of requests that hit your server, and the processing time of single requests. This can include Minification and Bundling of your CSS/JS files, refactoring your Javascript to do less roundtrips to the server, refactoring your controller/handler methods to be faster etc. I have added links below to Google and Yahoo recommendations.
6. Disable ASP.NET debugging in IIS.

Google and Yahoo recommendations:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules

https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

If you follow all these advices, i am sure you will get some improvements!